# Marking of data points after filtering

Tags: excel, vba, charts, filter

I want to mark a graph based on filtered datas. Unfortunately my code is using ALL datas instead of the filtered data, sothat the mapping wrong.

For the marking I want to use the first letter of the second and third column. The data starts at row number three. Can you tell me a solution to use only the visible data?

```
Sub BeschriftungDiagramm()

    Dim lngPunkt As Long
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gehaltsdaten")

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .ApplyDataLabels
        For lngPunkt = 1 To .Points.Count
            .Points(lngPunkt).DataLabel.Text = Left(data.Cells(lngPunkt + 2, _
                2), 1) & " " & Mid(data.Cells(lngPunkt + 2, 3), 2, 1)
        Next lngPunkt
    End With

End Sub
```

I hope you got enough information to understand my problem. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You could create a new worksheet (and hide it later if you like) and then record a macro of yourself filtering the data and copying the filtered data and pasting values to the new "filtered data" worksheet.  Then, link your chart to that data instead, and each time you want to update the chart you can run the recorded procedure any time you need to update the chart.

Comment: ... Depending on how often the source data changes, you could take it a step further and have the update procedure auto-run and to refresh the chart data any time the "actual" source data changes (using a worksheet event).

Comment: Hold on... maybe I'm misunderstand the problem: **Excel charts actually already ignore rows that are not visible** (either from filtering or from being hidden). ...so **are you only asking** how to filter data by the first letter of a column, or something like that?  If so, this is not a programming question, and also has nothing to do with charts.